# Оправданна ли CMS для сайта-визитки?

Tags: веб-программирование, cms

Оправдывает ли себя использование CMS (движка для сайта) для создания сайтов-визиток частных компаний?

Comment: Нет, не оправдано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Потому что:

- избыточно,
- сайты визитки пишутся быстро на html.

Answer (score 1):

Да. Если:

1. Вы не знакомы как минимум с HTML и CSS
2. Собираетесь часто обновлять сайт
3. Хотите иметь возможность быстро и удобно изменять информацию
4. Планируется расширение сайта (Иногда сайты визитки имеют такую тенденцию)

Answer (score 0):

уж лучше создавать "портфолио" на каком то готовом ресурсе, типа free-lance и ему подобных... З.ы если я не ошибаюсь есть какой то конструктор сайтов визиток, на котором делаешь своё портфолио с уже готовыми инструментами!
В общем соглашусь с постами выше!

Answer (score 0):

Одним словом холиварный вопрос, и как правило ответ, делайте что хотите, хоть на битрикс, всем все равно до лампочки. Но если там белобрысая секретарка, то ставить вам ЦМС в любом случае.

Answer (score -1):

Да. Т.к. это намного проще и удобнее (конечно, если соблюдены пункты выше).

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю тут ещё зависит от конкретной CMS, в принцепи если использовать минималистскую самописную кмс с минимумом кода, максимум функций, которое позволяет более лучше кешировать, а так же управлять gzip-сжатием, то думаю оправдано!

Comment: Я думаю тут речь как раз о том, чтобы использовать готовое решение и не писать ничего самому. А так, в принципе соглашусь.